# Do I have to spend 4 mana on Nissa, Steward of Elements to put 1 counter on her?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Do I have to cast [Nissa, Steward of Elements](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bNissa%2c%20Steward%20of%20Elements%5d) for 4 mana in order to put 1 loyalty counter on her?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If Nissa is cast for 4 mana, you are declaring X = 2, so she would enter the battlefield at 2 loyalty.

The minimum you can cast her and have her not immediately be put into the graveyard is 3 (X = 1).

Answer (score 5):

No, only three mana ({1}{G}{U}) is required for that.

First of all, note that X is not derived from the cost, the cost is derived from the X you choose. (This matters if there are cost increases or cost reductions in play.)

If you choose X=0, Nissa costs {G}{U} to cast<sup>[1]</sup>, and she enters the battlefield without any loyalty counters (and dies immediately after).

If you choose X=1, Nissa costs {1}{G}{U} to cast<sup>[1]</sup>, and she enters the battlefield with one loyalty counter.

If you choose X=2, Nissa costs {2}{G}{U} to cast<sup>[1]</sup>, and she enters the battlefield with two loyalty counters. This is the highest X you can choose if you have four mana.

---

1. Subject to cost increases and reductions, as usual.

Comment: Oath of Gideon as a caveat to X=0 causing Nissa to die.